# Iterate through MP3 files in folder and adding ID3 Tags to SQLite database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, parameters, transactions, bulkinsert

I'm using VB.Net and am trying to insert the ID3 tags in each file in a folder into a SQLite database.
I know how to iterate through a folder, and I also know how to extract the tags from an MP3 file, (I use Audio Tools Library (ATL) for .Net) for this purpose.

The problem I have is that when I loop through the files, I do not know how to insert the tags into the SQLite database as a bulk insert.

I understand that something like the following works . . .

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename' ('column1', 'column2') VALUES
 ('data1', 'data2'),
 ('data3', 'data4'),
 ('data5', 'data6'),
 ('data7', 'data8');
```

However I don't know how to add the appropriate tags to the 'data1', 'data2' information above.

Any advice would be appreciated.  I would also be happy with any C# code too.

++ EDIT ++

So I've discovered that the above doesn't work in SQLite, but I found something here on Transactions that looked promising, and I adapted it to the following -

```
        Dim FolderPath As String = "D:\MyMusic\Music\a-ha\Memorial Beach"
        Dim filePath As String = ""

        Dim CONNECTION_STR As String = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\bulkTest.db3; Version=3;"
        Dim objConn As SQLiteConnection

        objConn = New SQLiteConnection(CONNECTION_STR & "New=False;")

        objConn.Open()

        Using transaction = objConn.BeginTransaction()

            Using command = objConn.CreateCommand()

                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO albums(TrackName, TrackArtist, TrackAlbum) " & " VALUES($TrackName, $TrackArtist, $TrackAlbum);"

                Dim TrackNameParameter = command.CreateParameter()
                TrackNameParameter.ParameterName = "$TrackName"
                command.Parameters.Add(TrackNameParameter)

                Dim TrackArtistParameter = command.CreateParameter()
                TrackArtistParameter.ParameterName = "$TrackArtist"
                command.Parameters.Add(TrackArtistParameter)

                Dim TrackAlbumParameter = command.CreateParameter()
                TrackAlbumParameter.ParameterName = "$TrackAlbum"
                command.Parameters.Add(TrackAlbumParameter)

                For Each filePath In IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath)
                    Dim theTrack As New Track(filePath)
                    TrackNameParameter.Value = If(theTrack.Title.ToString, DBNull.Value)
                    TrackArtistParameter.Value = If(theTrack.Artist.ToString, DBNull.Value)
                    TrackAlbumParameter.Value = If(theTrack.Album.ToString, DBNull.Value)
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next

                transaction.Commit()

            End Using

        End Using

        objConn.Close()

        MsgBox("Done.")
```

When I run the above I don't get any errors, however the rows it inserts into the database are empty of data.

I have checked that the code

```
Dim theTrack As New Track(filePath)
```

does in-fact return data.  Can anyone see anything out of place?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, thanks for the suggestion.  Yes I did use the debugger, and determined that the data is being extracted from the MP3 files ok, it's just not being written to the database. The rows are being inserted, and null strings are being inserted into the values instead of the returned ID3 tags.  I suspect I'll have to dig into how the parameters are being populated.

Comment: Perhaps write a program that populates the DB using constant values and make sure that works and then go from there?

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity.  I changed the parameters to constant values and got the same result.  I have written data to SQLite databases many times without any problem, it's just that this is my first time trying to insert bulk items.  I have been under the impression that writing single records via a loop is very inefficient and can bog down the application if there are a lot of records.  Oh well, I'll keep plodding on I guess.  Thanks for taking an interest.

Comment: What is the result of this expression? If(theTrack.Title.ToString, DBNull.Value)

Comment: Hi Andrew.  I have placed a msgBox() for any of the three If(theTrack.Title.ToString, DBNull.Value) or  If(theTrack.Artist.ToString, DBNull.Value) or If(theTrack.Album.ToString, DBNull.Value) just before the ExecuteNonQuery command, and get what I'm expecting to see.  So the data is being lost somewhere after the  command.ExecuteNonQuery() has run.

Comment: As it's a program just for me, I have reverted to saving each record one at a time - with an application.doevents() between each write.  It works, but I just feel that it's not at all efficient.

Comment: But,  that's what the code in your question does - it writes records one at a time. Application.DoEvents  is irrelevant here (it purely tells the thread that is managing the messages queue to process ui updates, redraw labels etc) and whatever you're doing should work without it. Personally I would try removing the transaction; it isn't doing anything for you here

Comment: I would also check as a side inquiry that your db isn't being replaced with a blank one every time you build as is the risk when you have a db file in your project witth CopyToOutput set to Always. It can be very confusing if the build process is overwribbg your db with an empty one all the time

Comment: Thanks Caius, I have checked that the database wasn't being replaced - and it wasn't. I've reverted to my old code and all is working fine.  I appreciate you all taking the time to answer . . . cheers.